# Unable to get Spring Framework Debug messages logged

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, spring-security, log4j

I am working with Spring 4.3.1 Security. I have included following dependencies for logging.

1). log4j-1.2.17.jar
2).commons-logging-1.2.jar

In the `log4j.properties` file, I have included the following.

> log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
>   log4j.category.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

I am not getting any Spring Debug message logged by the Logger. I am getting all the messages that I have created logged correctly.

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: what is the path of your log4j.properties file?

Comment: Ashish, the log4j.properties file is present in the classpath. I am getting my own messages logged correctly so setup of Log4j is fine I believe.

Comment: Please check this link 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/  for spring mvc   and 
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm for java application.

Comment: Ranjit, I have read those posts. As I told, Logging is setup correctly. My own messages are getting logged but Spring Framework internal messages are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue lies in the use of Websphere as the Web Server. The settings worked fine on Tomcat and I was able to see all the logs.

Apparently, the in-built Commons-Logging implementation in Websphere takes precedence over that provided by any application deployed on Websphere. I haven't been able to find a solution/workaround for this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use *logger* instead of *category*:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Loggers were called "categories" in early versions of Log4J.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.